# What are all the nutrients in the USDA composition API?

Tags: api

I am working on a data visualization app using the [USDA API](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/doc/apilist/API-FOOD-REPORTV2.md). I am pulling the foods and extracting the nutrients, of which there are usually 90-150 different values. I want to get a sum of different groupings of nutrients, but am not sure what goes in each group as the IDs jump around.

For example, I am not sure if Minerals should use IDs `301-317` or `[301, 303, ... 312, 315, 317]`.

Is there a location with all these nutrients and IDs laid out in english? I've checked the [nutrient list/search](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/nutrients/index) and the PDF description in the [full USDA ACCESS database](https://www.ars.usda.gov/northeast-area/beltsville-md/beltsville-human-nutrition-research-center/nutrient-data-laboratory/docs/sr28-download-files/) download but haven't been able to find what I'm looking for.

[image]

Edit: I could use their groups to process summations, but unfortunately there is repeated data in some nutrient groups. For example, I believe there are individual isoflavone fields and a 'Total Isoflavone' field, summing would double count.

Comment: It seems that each of the nutrients has a unique name. Why can not you process them? Please provide an example of JSON data that you want to receive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see all the nutrition information on the USDA's SR28 reference guid [here](https://www.ars.usda.gov/ARSUserFiles/80400525/Data/SR/SR28/sr28_doc.pdf), page 16.

I used [usda-sqlite](https://github.com/alyssaq/usda-sqlite) to process the data into SQLite. Then uploaded it to https://sqliteonline.com/ and ran custom SQL commands.

### SQL

- `SELECT * FROM  nutrient;` - print out all the potential nutrients & their data. Yay!
- `SELECT Count(*) FROM  food;` - 8789
- `SELECT Count(*) FROM  food where food_group_id !=300 and food_group_id !=3500` - 8257 - Exclude all baby food and Native American food
- `SELECT id FROM  food;` - [ [food.id] ]
- `SELECT id,long_desc FROM  food;` - [ [food.id, food.long_desc] ]
- `SELECT id,name FROM  nutrient;` - [ [nutrient.id, nutrient.name] ]
- `SELECT count(*),food_group.name FROM food inner join food_group on food.food_group_id=food_group.id group by food_group_id;` - the count of all the foods in each food group

Every food's serving size, if it has one

```
SELECT 
  food.id,
  food.long_desc,
  gm_weight
FROM  food 
INNER JOIN weight ON weight.food_id=food.id
where weight.description=='serving';
```

Nutrient amounts per 100g of food

```
SELECT 
  food.id,
  nutrient.name,
  nutrition.amount
FROM  nutrition 
INNER JOIN food ON nutrition.food_id=food.id 
INNER JOIN nutrient ON nutrition.nutrient_id=nutrient.id;
```

#### Post processing

You can export this data to JSON and do further processing, like indexing.

Example: After exporting to JSON (use the button in the top left) the final example returns an array of `[food.id,nutrient.id,nutrition.amount]` for every food matching the WHERE clause. You may want to index this to speed up searches and cut down on file size (otherwise there's lots of repeat `food.id` data in those arrays). After doing this my JSON reduced from ~10MB to 7.0MB.

```
    let b = Amt.reduce((total, curr) => {
        const foodId = curr[0];
        const nutrientId = curr[1];
        const amt = curr[2];
        const foodIsNew = !(foodId in total);
        if (foodIsNew) total[foodId] = {};
        total[foodId][nutrientId] = amt;
        return total;
    }, {})
    console.log(JSON.stringify(b)); //note this add " characters to the beginning and end when printing to the console
```

### Update

It looks like the available SQL is out of date with respect to what's available on the FDA API. I wrote a script to plug into the API and grab all the nutrient names and shove them all into one object. This is the result:

```
{
    "203": "Protein",
    "204": "Total lipid (fat)",
    "205": "Carbohydrate, by difference",
    "207": "Ash",
    "208": "Energy",
    "209": "Starch",
    "210": "Sucrose",
    "211": "Glucose (dextrose)",
    "212": "Fructose",
    "213": "Lactose",
    "214": "Maltose",
    "221": "Alcohol, ethyl",
    "255": "Water",
    "257": "Adjusted Protein",
    "262": "Caffeine",
    "263": "Theobromine",
    "268": "Energy",
    "269": "Sugars, total",
    "287": "Galactose",
    "291": "Fiber, total dietary",
    "301": "Calcium, Ca",
    "303": "Iron, Fe",
    "304": "Magnesium, Mg",
    "305": "Phosphorus, P",
    "306": "Potassium, K",
    "307": "Sodium, Na",
    "309": "Zinc, Zn",
    "312": "Copper, Cu",
    "313": "Fluoride, F",
    "315": "Manganese, Mn",
    "317": "Selenium, Se",
    "318": "Vitamin A, IU",
    "319": "Retinol",
    "320": "Vitamin A, RAE",
    "321": "Carotene, beta",
    "322": "Carotene, alpha",
    "323": "Vitamin E",
    "324": "Vitamin D",
    "325": "Vitamin D2",
    "326": "Vitamin D3",
    "328": "Vitamin D (D2 + D3)",
    "334": "Cryptoxanthin, beta",
    "337": "Lycopene",
    "338": "Lutein + zeaxanthin",
    "341": "Tocopherol, beta",
    "342": "Tocopherol, gamma",
    "343": "Tocopherol, delta",
    "401": "Vitamin C",
    "404": "Thiamin",
    "405": "Riboflavin",
    "406": "Niacin",
    "410": "Pantothenic acid",
    "415": "Vitamin B-6",
    "417": "Folate, total",
    "418": "Vitamin B-12",
    "421": "Choline, total",
    "430": "Vitamin K (phylloquinone)",
    "431": "Folic acid",
    "432": "Folate, food",
    "435": "Folate, DFE",
    "454": "Betaine",
    "501": "Tryptophan",
    "502": "Threonine",
    "503": "Isoleucine",
    "504": "Leucine",
    "505": "Lysine",
    "506": "Methionine",
    "507": "Cystine",
    "508": "Phenylalanine",
    "509": "Tyrosine",
    "510": "Valine",
    "511": "Arginine",
    "512": "Histidine",
    "513": "Alanine",
    "514": "Aspartic acid",
    "515": "Glutamic acid",
    "516": "Glycine",
    "517": "Proline",
    "518": "Serine",
    "521": "Hydroxyproline",
    "573": "Vitamin E, added",
    "578": "Vitamin B-12, added",
    "601": "Cholesterol",
    "605": "Trans Fat",
    "606": "Saturated Fat",
    "607": "4:0",
    "608": "6:0",
    "609": "8:0",
    "610": "10:0",
    "611": "12:0",
    "612": "14:0",
    "613": "16:0",
    "614": "18:0",
    "615": "20:0",
    "617": "18:1 undifferentiated",
    "618": "18:2 undifferentiated",
    "619": "18:3 undifferentiated",
    "620": "20:4 undifferentiated",
    "621": "DHA",
    "624": "22:0",
    "625": "14:1",
    "626": "16:1 undifferentiated",
    "627": "18:4",
    "628": "20:1",
    "629": "EPA",
    "630": "22:1 undifferentiated",
    "631": "DPA",
    "636": "Phytosterols",
    "638": "Stigmasterol",
    "639": "Campesterol",
    "641": "Beta-sitosterol",
    "645": "Monounsaturated Fat",
    "646": "Polyunsaturated Fat",
    "652": "15:0",
    "653": "17:0",
    "654": "24:0",
    "662": "16:1 t",
    "663": "18:1 t",
    "664": "22:1 t",
    "665": "18:2 t not further defined",
    "666": "18:2 i",
    "669": "18:2 t,t",
    "670": "18:2 CLAs",
    "671": "24:1 c",
    "672": "20:2 n-6 c,c",
    "673": "16:1 c",
    "674": "18:1 c",
    "675": "18:2 n-6 c,c",
    "676": "22:1 c",
    "685": "18:3 n-6 c,c,c",
    "687": "17:1",
    "689": "20:3 undifferentiated",
    "693": "Fatty acids, total trans-monoenoic",
    "696": "13:0",
    "697": "15:1",
    "710": "Daidzein",
    "711": "Genistein",
    "712": "Glycitein",
    "713": "Total isoflavones",
    "714": "Biochanin A",
    "715": "Formononetin",
    "716": "Coumestrol",
    "731": "Cyanidin",
    "734": "Proanthocyanidin dimers",
    "735": "Proanthocyanidin trimers",
    "736": "Proanthocyanidin 4-6mers",
    "737": "Proanthocyanidin 7-10mers",
    "738": "Proanthocyanidin polymers (>10mers)",
    "740": "Petunidin",
    "741": "Delphinidin",
    "742": "Malvidin",
    "743": "Pelargonidin",
    "745": "Peonidin",
    "749": "(+)-Catechin",
    "750": "(-)-Epigallocatechin",
    "751": "(-)-Epicatechin",
    "752": "(-)-Epicatechin 3-gallate",
    "753": "(-)-Epigallocatechin 3-gallate",
    "758": "Eriodictyol",
    "759": "Hesperetin",
    "762": "Naringenin",
    "770": "Apigenin",
    "773": "Luteolin",
    "785": "Isorhamnetin",
    "786": "Kaempferol",
    "788": "Myricetin",
    "789": "Quercetin",
    "794": "(+)-Gallocatechin",
    "851": "ALA",
    "853": "20:3 n-6",
    "855": "20:4 n-6",
    "856": "18:3i",
    "857": "21:5",
    "858": "22:4"
}
```

Comment: I've checked a couple of food entries, and I see this list has grown. Can't find any documentation with full list of current codes though.

Answer (score 1):

If you download the [supporting data zip file](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-datasets/FoodData_Central_Supporting_Data_csv_2020-04-29.zip) on the USDA's website, you can find a csv file called 'nutrient.csv'. Within, you'll find all the nutrient_id's with their associated name.

Snippet of csv file:

```
"id","name","unit_name","nutrient_nbr","rank"
"1002","Nitrogen","G","202","500"
"1003","Protein","G","203","600"
"1004","Total lipid (fat)","G","204","800"
"1005","Carbohydrate, by difference","G","205","1110"
"1007","Ash","G","207","1000"
"1008","Energy","KCAL","208","300"
"1009","Starch","G","209","2200"
"1010","Sucrose","G","210","1600"
"1011","Glucose (dextrose)","G","211","1700"
"1012","Fructose","G","212","1800"
```